# Serializer Validate() method not invoking in serializer DRF

Tags: python, django, serialization

In DRF the serializer `validate()` method is not calling by default.

i am using the serializer like this:

```py
class SampleListView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Sample.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SampleSerializer
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(sorted_result)

class SampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    custom_data = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = SampleModel
        fields = ('field_1', 'field_2')

    def validate(self, data):
        return data
```

Execution not enter into the validate() method in serializer.

Anyone have an idea about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shijo `Validate()` only be called when you are using save method of serializer hence only be used for create and update method of API.
As refer in Validation in DRF documentation

> you always need to call is_valid() before attempting to access the validated data, or save an object instance.

Comment: thanks @Muhammed . I did that validation in my view `get_queryset()` method. it's work for me.

Comment: @Shijo Please accept this answer to help others in community.